# Is there any way to know the command-line options available for a separate program from Python?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am relatively new to the python's **subprocess** and **os** modules. So, I was able to do the process execution like running **bc**, **cat** commands with python and putting the data in **stdin** and taking the result from **stdout**.

Now I want to first know that a process like **cat** accepts what flags through python code (If it is possible).

Then I want to execute a particular command with some flags set.

I googled it for both things and it seems that I got the solution for second one but with multiple ways. So, if anyone know how to do these things and do it in some standard kind of way, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What flags are you talking about? Do you mean things like the `-l` in `ls -l`? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: yes,

and i want to know that if there is some method which perform function like "man" in terminal

Comment: You typically will need to call the command with `-h` or `--help` option and parse the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of processes, those flags are called arguments, hence also the argument vector called `argv`. Their interpretation is 100% up to the program called. In other words, you have to read the manpages or other documentation for the programs you want to call.

There is one caveat though: If you don't invoke a program directly but via a shell, that shell is the actual process being started. It then also interprets wildcards. For example, if you run `cat` with the argument vector `['*']`, it will output the content of the file named `*` if it exists or an error if it doesn't. If you run `/bin/sh` with `['-c', 'cat *']`, the shell will first resolve `*` into all entries in the current directory and then pass these as separate arguments to `cat`.

Comment: While Docker (like some of the worse `ps` and `top` tools) logs what it's running as `sh -c cat *` without making argument boundaries clear, that's a dangerous omission and shouldn't be followed as an example; the argv is better written as `sh -c 'cat *'` or `['sh', '-c', 'cat *']`, making it clear that everything parsed as code is included in a single argument immediately after `-c` (whereas later arguments go into `$0`, `$1`, etc. and are thereafter unused unless the code in the argument immediately following `-c` refers to them).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. What has Docker got to do with the question?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  Your answer made no attempt to answer the OP"s question.

Comment: @fpmurphy, I mentioned Docker as one of the places that Ulrich could be getting the faulty `sh -c cat *` representation that they used in the answer as originally written. It was a comment on the answer, not the question, for a reason.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to represent `argv` as list of strings, @CharlesDuffy, to make that distinction.